# Declaring a pointer with a scope resolution operator in the name

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make sence of this tutorial on doubly linked lists. 
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/53161-how-to-create-a-basic-double-linked-list/

I can't understand this part

```
  element* list::FirstEl = NULL;    //This initialises the static element* 'FirstEl' to  NULL  
  element* list::LastEl = NULL;     //This initialises the static element* 'LastEl' to
```

I would say this code creates a pointer of type element with the name "list::FirstEl" and sets it to null, but the scope resolution operator makes me think there is something I still havn't covered in C++ yet.

What's going on here?

Comment: Like with most things c, you read it right to left: In this statement (;), the value 'Null' is assigned (=) to 'FirstEl' which is a member variable (::) of the object 'list', and it is a pointer (*) to an object of the type 'element'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a `static` class member initializtion.

```
class list
{
    static element* FirstEl;
    static element* LastEl;
};
```

what you have there is the initialization of the members.

The name of the variables are `FirstEl` and `LastEl`, but they are part of the class, that's why you have to qualify their names when you define them.

Just like you'd qualify method names when you'd define them.